# Getting android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception for layout file

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm getting rare crash reports from users about crash with message:
`Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
File res/layout/game_dialog_game_ended.xml from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f03001c`

Here is a link to full description of exception.
http://crashes.to/s/419d864f3af

It is received only from a few users but a reason of such behaviour is interesting.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Contents of game_dialog_game_ended.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_game_stop_rating"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry,RtlHardcoded" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_game_stop_show_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/game_ended_show_table"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_games_badge_leaderboards"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_game_stop_show_table"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/game_ended_rating"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_game_stop_rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_game_stop_rating_change"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_game_stop_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/game_ended_sign_in"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_game_stop_show_table_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/game_ended_show_table"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this crash happens during orientation change or normally ?

Comment: can you paste your __game_dialog_game_ended.xml__ code here?

Comment: I don't exactly know when that crash happens - due to orientation change or first show.